# Updating totals in a CSV file PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to update a file that is blocked out like this

```
0,0,5,2,0
0,0,7,0,0
0,2,2,3,0
1,2,2,2,0
0,0,5,2,0
0,1,3,2,1
0,0,3,2,2
0,0,6,1,0
```

Each row is a question and each number in the row is the number of respondents. Here the code is attempting to go row by row and check which answer the user picked out of 5 radio buttons per question.  So the format is something like:

```
Question 1: Blah              |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  | Check one

//Grab user input from survey
$q[1] = $_POST['radio1'];
$q[2] = $_POST['radio2'];
$q[3] = $_POST['radio3'];
$q[4] = $_POST['radio4'];
$q[5] = $_POST['radio5'];
$q[6] = $_POST['radio6'];
$q[7] = $_POST['radio7'];
$q[8] = $_POST['radio8'];

//Use file handle and write to file
$FileName = "results.csv";
$FileHandle = fopen($FileName, 'a+') or die("can't open file!!");


$i = 0;

while($row = fgetcsv($FileHandle)){
    $j = 1;
    for($i = 0; $i<8; $i++){
        if($q[$j] == 1){
            $row[0]++;
        }
        else if($q[$j] == 2){
            $row[1]++;
        }
        else if($q[$j] == 3){
            $row[2]++;
        }
        else if($q[$j] == 4){
            $row[3]++;
        }
        else if($q[$j] == 5){
            $row[4]++;
        }
        $j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still working on a solution to my new issue, attempting to just update the row values that are pulled in from fgetcsv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to my problem, it may not be elegant but it works.  The script has to pull in the values and update them at the end.

```
<?php

//Grab user input from survey
$q[1] = $_POST['radio1'];
$q[2] = $_POST['radio2'];
$q[3] = $_POST['radio3'];
$q[4] = $_POST['radio4'];
$q[5] = $_POST['radio5'];
$q[6] = $_POST['radio6'];
$q[7] = $_POST['radio7'];
$q[8] = $_POST['radio8'];

//Use file handle and write to file
$FileName = "results.csv";
$FileHandle = fopen($FileName, 'r') or die("can't open file!!");

$result = array();

$i = 0;
$j = 1;
while(($row = fgetcsv($FileHandle, 1024, ",")) !== FALSE){

    if($q[$j] == 1){
        $temp[0] = $row[0] + 1;
        $temp[1] = $row[1];
        $temp[2] = $row[2];
        $temp[3] = $row[3];
        $temp[4] = $row[4]; 
    }
    else if($q[$j] == 2){
        $temp[0] = $row[0];
        $temp[1] = $row[1] + 1;
        $temp[2] = $row[2];
        $temp[3] = $row[3];
        $temp[4] = $row[4];
    }
    else if($q[$j] == 3){
        $temp[0] = $row[0];
        $temp[1] = $row[1];
        $temp[2] = $row[2] + 1;
        $temp[3] = $row[3];
        $temp[4] = $row[4];
    }
    else if($q[$j] == 4){
        $temp[0] = $row[0];
        $temp[1] = $row[1];
        $temp[2] = $row[2];
        $temp[3] = $row[3] + 1;
        $temp[4] = $row[4];
    }
    else if($q[$j] == 5){
        $temp[0] = $row[0];
        $temp[1] = $row[1];
        $temp[2] = $row[2];
        $temp[3] = $row[3];
        $temp[4] = $row[4] + 1;
    }
    $result[] = $temp;
    $j++;
}
fclose($FileHandle);

$FileHandle = fopen($FileName, 'w') or die("can't open file!!");


foreach($result as $line){
    fputcsv($FileHandle, $line);
}

fclose($FileHandle);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape sequences such as `\n` are not interpolated within single quotes.

You have to use double quotes:

```
$result = $q1.','.$q2.','.$q3.','.$q4.','.$q5.','.$q6.','.$q7.','.$q8."\n";
```

Also, you should take a look at the [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/fputcsv) function.

Comment: Oh, thank you.  I will read up on that, I wasn't aware that that function even existed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fwrite, check fputcsv() : http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php this will give you far more flexibility than string concantenation.

e.g

```
$q[1] = $_POST['radio1'];
$q[2] = $_POST['radio2'];
$q[3] = $_POST['radio3'];
$q[4] = $_POST['radio4'];
$q[5] = $_POST['radio5'];
$q[6] = $_POST['radio6'];
$q[7] = $_POST['radio7'];
$q[8] = $_POST['radio8'];

fputcsv($FileHandlem $q);
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully, so next step is to, stop me if i'm wrong: Read in each line of the csv -> Find a way to update the correct entry -> Write that line back to the correct location to update the file.  So I will update line by line checking the value of q as I go e.g. if `q1 = 3` this means a neutral response so if row one is `0,0,0,0,0` after I update it should turn out `0,0,1,0,0`.

Comment: Why do you need to read the CSV before saving it? Surely you should write the CSV with the updated information?

Comment: Maybe I am approaching the problem wrong. I have to increment the values in the file, q's value is the location where it needs to be updated, so I thought that I had to pick up all the values and check what q's value was and update that location in the line.  q1 is line one of the file and the number it holds is the column that needs to be updated. My test example above is not actually what i'm trying to accomplish, that was simply to figure out CSV.